# Displays won't stay off when I put them to sleep in MacOS

Tags: macos, display, energy-saving

In MacOS, when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>Eject</kbd> the displays go blank for a second, then they turn on again.
There's no way I can get them off permanently.
I also don't want the computer to sleep as I leave it downloading over night.
I have a MacBook with an external monitor attached.

Comment: Does the same still happen without the external display? Also, have you tried without any USB peripherals plugged in.

Comment: @Mike to both questions, I would say yes, but not 100% sure, gonna try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just lower the internal screen's brightness to the lowest level (pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, depending on your preferences), this will turn the lights off.

Turn off the external screen using its power button.

Comment: Thanks, but this function is there for a reason, so one doesn't have to do what you describe. It should work but it's not working. Thanks anyway.